# Проблема с установкой .NET Framework

Tags: .net, install

После того, как я удалил все старые версии .NET Framework, и попытался установить новую (да, потому что я идиот, и понял, что делать этого не стоило), но при попытке установки выдает ошибку, мол, у меня уже есть более новая версия, хотя на самом деле его, по идее, нет вообще

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, у вас была версия, и вы её удалили вручную?

Comment: Да, именно так и было. Удалил через "Удаление программ"

Comment: Тогда может быть вам поможет Repait Tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135 ?

Comment: Ничего кроме огромной кучи логов он мне не сделал

Comment: Та же фигня, что и у автора. Из-за этого вижуалка никак не встанет.